# Изменение цвета "пирожка"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу, чтобы при наведении на пирожок все 3 линии становились синими.
А у меня цвет меняется только тогда, когда я навожу курсор на линию(только её цвет и меняется).
Заранее спасибо.
Вот мой css код:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

html:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>Men's Might(здесь можно лого)</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="health.html">Health</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Power</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Attraction</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Force</a></li>                  
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Хочется, чтобы при наведении на пирожок все линии меняли цвет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: html-код дайте.

Comment: Написал html в вопрсе

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, ваш код запускаемым, а я вам помогу.

Comment: Буду благодарен, если скажете как это сделать.

Comment: Там [кнопка есть такая](http://prntscr.com/e5o6ba) с помощью которой можно это сделать.

Comment: @Ravdan В целом вы действуете неверно, что для линий создаёте три `span` вместо одного. Есть unicode-символ для меню-гамбургера (☰).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Этот код сделал фон синим, не линии.

Comment: @Ravdan нет. Внимательней смотрите.

Comment: Я попробовал, изменяется фон на синий при наведении.

Comment: @Ravdan этот селектор меняет фон стрелок .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar Возможно не до конца скопировали.

Comment: @Ravdan вы делаете что-то не так. Этот код меняет фон именно трёх линий

Comment: Всё верно. Спасибо. .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover .
Невнимательный...

Comment: Сейчас всё работает.